Why is sudo accepting hashed password?
I'm using buildroot to generate a BusyBox based Linux and recently added sudo.
At first it would not accept my password ("user") so on a whim I used su to switch to the root user, copied the hashed password in /etc/shadow, switched back to my user (named "user"), ran sudo ls, pasted in the password and it worked?
Dramatic recreation below:
$ whoami
user
$ su
$ cat /etc/shadow
root::::::::
daemon:*:::::::
bin:*:::::::
sys:*:::::::
sync:*:::::::
mail:*:::::::
www-data:*:::::::
operator:*:::::::
nobody:*:::::::
sshd:*:::::::
user:$5$7AAMbV/R$xbGLljZDpzFCy6ReMyC1er53lFJgqRCgvZJnGrc7Q9A:::::::
$ su user
$ sudo ls -la 
Password: <-- typed "user" here
Sorry, try again.
Password: <-- pasted above hashed password here
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 user     user          4096 Jan  1 00:00 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Aug 24  2024 ..
-rw-------    1 user     user           156 Jan  1 01:05 .ash_history
$ 

How/why is this happening and is there a way to fix this?
I've been able to make sudo work properly by adding PAM but I'd rather avoid adding that if possible.

See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/do-sites-store-login-password-with-hash-if-so-can-people-can-use-hash-collisio for similar question

When not using PAM, you must build sudo with crypt() support. This function provides the password hashing algorithms that are used in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow; without it, sudo can only do a direct comparison.
The crypt() function used to be provided by libc, but has been moved to the external libxcrypt on modern systems; it seems that the corresponding AC_CHECK_LIBS sudo's configure.ac has not been updated to detect libxcrypt yet, so you might need either to patch it yourself, or to make sure libxcrypt is built with "obsolete" API enabled.
